# C error: missing whitespace after the macro name

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I wrote the following macro:

```
#define m[a,b] m.values[m.rows*(a)+(b)]
```

However gcc gives me this error:

```
error: missing whitespace after the macro name
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `[` and `]` as delimiters for macro arguments; you must use `(` and `)`.  Try this:

```
#define m(a,b) m.values[m.rows*(a)+(b)]
```

But note that defining the name of a macro as the name of an existing variable may be confusing.  You should avoid shadowing names like this.

Comment: My aim was to be able to create a matrix myMat, and access elements with myMat[i, j]. I guess it doesn't work that way. I'll accept after the time limit ;)

Comment: If you were using C++ you could override the indexer to do exactly this.  C doesn't really have anything directly comparable.

Comment: I know, I come from C++ and C# where I'm used to that. I was hoping I could somehow twist the C pre-processor into giving me the same thing.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use an appropriate pointer-to-VLA type for the matrix, but then you couldn't put it in a structure..

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with any C preprocessor syntax that uses square brackets. Change

```
  #define m[a,b] m.values[m.rows*(a)+(b)]
```

to

```
  #define m(a,b) m.values[m.rows*(a)+(b)]
```

And it should work.

Comment: He should actually use something like this:
`#define elem(matrix, row, column) matrix.values[matrix.rows*(row) + column]`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have such a macro that will expand when you supply arguments in **square** brackets. Wherever you got the idea that macros are a ***smart*** text-substituting tool, it's just the other way round: macros are extremely ***obtuse and stupid*** text-substitution mechanism. What you're trying to do with a macro is absolutely unwarranted - just write a named function.